# If number of child div is > 3, hide the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if anyone had a smart way of doing this:

I have some dynamically generated html, and it generates some divs based on the database.

```
<div class="category_items">
    <div class="category_item"></div>
    <div class="category_item"></div>
    <div class="category_item"></div>          
</div>
```

If this number is > 3, I need to hide those extra. When the user clicks a button, its going to show those that were hidden, and then if the user clicks again they will disappear again.

This is my current js code, which finds which divs that have to many children (it works):

```
    // Checks the number of items pr. category, if > 3, hide the rest of them
    var categories = $categoriesDiv.children();

    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; ++i) {
        var localCategoryItems = $('.category_items', categories[i]);

        // Hide elements if length is > 3
        if (localCategoryItems.children().length > 3) {
            console.log('hide');
        }
    }
```

I just need a smart way to hide and show the extra children. Thanks!

Comment: You should just use CSS and a small piece of jQuery to show/hide. Just the ".category_items div:nth-child(n+4)" selector will do it. Use it on the CSS and on the jQuery. Example is provided bellow.

Comment: can you share html for `categoriesDiv`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the pseudo selector nth-child this way:

```
.category_items div:nth-child(n+4) 
{
    display: none;
}
```

Example is provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/AK4c2/1/

**UPDATED:** the link has been updated and the jQuery could be as follows:

```
$(".showhide").click(function()
{
     $(".category_items div:nth-child(n+4)").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Older browsers may not support it, but ... who needs them!!

Answer (score 6):

You can user the [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) filter to find out children with index > 2

```
localCategoryItems.children(':gt(2)').hide()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
 $('.category_item:gt(2)').hide();
```

gt(2) will represents greaterthan 2 .It will hides the categories_items that greaterthan 3 because that count will statr from '0'

Answer (score 1):

To hide elements with the class `.category_items` that has more than 3 children, and to toggle the visibility of those elements, you'd do something like :

```
var elems = $('.category_item', '.category_items').filter(function() {
                return $(this).children().length > 3;
            }).hide();

$('button').on('click', function() {
    elems.toggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/S5JcL/)

Answer (score 0):

Just mark the 'extra' items with a class and toggle visibility of that items in your click handler:

```
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; ++i) {
   var localCategoryItems = $('.category_items', categories[i]);

   // Hide elements if length is > 3
   if (localCategoryItems.children().length > 3) {
      localCategoryItems.find(':gt(2)').addClass('extra');
   }
}

$('#showHideButton').click(function(e) {
    $('.category_items.extra').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the @Wallack answer the part to change the show/hide text on toggle.

```
$(".showhide").click(function () {
    $(".category_items div:nth-child(n+4)").toggle(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
            $(".showhide").text("Show more");
        } else {
            $(".showhide").text("Show less");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("button")
    if (!tgt.id || tgt.id != "toggle") return;
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".category_items .category_item")]
    .slice(3)
    .forEach(div => div.hidden = !div.hidden);
    tgt.textContent = tgt.textContent === "read more..." ? "read less..." : "read more...";    
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="category_items">
  <div class="category_item">1</div>
  <div class="category_item">2</div>
  <div class="category_item">3</div>
  <div class="category_item" hidden>4</div>
  <div class="category_item" hidden>5</div>
</div>
<button id="toggle">read more...</button>
```